# T-SQL Query to replace a symbol or character in one xml node value of XML data type column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to replace plus symbol with underscore in the one xml node of a particular table.
Example: In the below input, i want to replace plus symbol only in filepath node and NOT filename node.
**Table column data type is XML and NOT varchar.**

Input:

```
 <mediadata>
  <image>
    <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
    <FilePath>/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/BUF2011-450.jpg</FilePath>
    <Thumbnails>
      <Thumbnail>
        <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
        <FilePath>/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/thumb_BUF2011-450_Large.jpg</FilePath>
      </Thumbnail>
      <Thumbnail>
        <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
        <FilePath>/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/thumb_BUF2011-450_Small.jpg</FilePath>
      </Thumbnail>
    </Thumbnails>
  </image>
</mediadata>
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I have file path node multiple times in the xml under various decedents. I am not able to figure out for a query to update all of them

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I am all set and have copy pasted the same update statement 3 times in my script to support different xpaths in the xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T table(XMLCol xml)

insert into @T values
('<image>
    <FileName>Tim+bottom</FileName>
    <FilePath>/Top+Bottom/AFX8995+450.jpg</FilePath>
  </image>')

update T set
  XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/image/FilePath[1]/text())[1] 
                 with sql:column("T2.FilePath")')
from @T as T
  cross apply (select replace(XMLCol.value('(/image/FilePath)[1]', 
                                           'varchar(100)'), 
                              '+', 
                              '_')
              ) as T2(FilePath)
```

**Edit**

The table variable `@T` above is instead of your table. Assume that your table is named `YourTable` and you have one `ID` column and `XMLCol` column. The update statement could look like this to change the XML where `ID` is 1.

```
update T set
  XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/image/FilePath[1]/text())[1] 
                 with sql:column("T2.FilePath")')
from YourTable as T
  cross apply (select replace(XMLCol.value('(/image/FilePath)[1]', 
                                           'varchar(100)'), 
                              '+', 
                              '_')
              ) as T2(FilePath)      
where T.ID = 1
```

**Edit**

It is not possible to update more than one node at a time with `.modify()`. You have to do this in a loop. The script below uses `@T` as a test table. You should replace that with whatever your table is called. `@T` has an `ID` column and the script assumes that you only update one row at a time and that you know the ID for that row. There are some comments in the code that explains what I do. Don't hesitate to ask if there are something I should make clearer.

```
-- Test table
declare @T table(ID int, XMLCol xml)

-- Sample data
insert into @T values
(1,
 '<mediadata>
    <image>
      <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
      <FilePath>1/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/BUF2011-450.jpg</FilePath>
      <Thumbnails>
        <Thumbnail>
          <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
          <FilePath>2/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/thumb_BUF2011-450_Large.jpg</FilePath>
        </Thumbnail>
        <Thumbnail>
          <FileName>BUF2011-450</FileName>
          <FilePath>3/uploadedImages/Products/Indoor_Fun/Puzzles___Brain_Teasers/Puzzles/2000+_Pieces/thumb_BUF2011-450_Small.jpg</FilePath>
        </Thumbnail>
      </Thumbnails>
    </image>
  </mediadata>
')

-- ID for the row you need to update
declare @ID int
set @ID = 1

-- Loop variable, node to update
declare @Pos int
set @Pos = 1

-- The number of nodes to update
declare @Count int

-- Get the number of FilePath nodes
select @Count = XMLCol.query('count(//FilePath)').value('.', 'int')
from @T
where ID = @ID

while @Pos <= @Count
begin
  update T set
    XMLCol.modify('replace value of ((//FilePath)[sql:variable("@Pos")]/text())[1] 
                   with sql:column("T2.FilePath")')
  from @T as T
    cross apply (select replace(T.XMLCol.
                                  query('(//FilePath)[sql:variable("@Pos")]').
                                  value('.', 'varchar(100)'), 
                                '+', 
                                '_')
                ) as T2(FilePath)      
  where T.ID = @ID                 

  set @Pos += 1            
end
```

Comment: +1 for doing it right and not 'cheating' by casting to varchar(max)!

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson ..I am kind of confused because I have 1 million records and only few records have problems so how does this work without a where clause to update only those records. can you please write a syntax as if the table and column already exists in the database like update table_name set column_name = '_' etc etc to understand easily

Comment: Mikael's code is basically doing: `UPDATE TABLE set filepath = REPLACE(filepath, '+', '_')` It works differently in XML though. The XML Methods don't permit much tsql, so he is basically joining to a query that exposes that value as a column (the cross apply), applying the TSQL function to perform the replace, then replacing the old value with the new value (xmlCol.modify()).

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson  I have file path node multiple times in the xml under various decedents. I am not able to figure out a query to update all of them values..See the updated input in the question

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson .. I am all set and have copy pasted the same update statement 3 times in my script to support different xpaths in the xml. Thank you again for the help

Comment: @user - I have added a version that updates all `FilePath` nodes for **one row** where you know the ID.